# Does Flutter automatically set the targetSdkVersion to the latest version on SDK version you have in your machine?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I uploaded an android application. And one of the clients had the latest version of Android, and could not install it. I updated the SDK to version 33, will flutter automatically change my targetSdkVersion?

Answer (score -1):

In the application level build.gradle you can set targetSdkVersion

```
    defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.test.appname"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: While these are instructions how to change it manually, it does not answer the question if it is updated automatically. Can you provide insights on that?

Comment: No there is not support for targetSdkVersion change from flutter side, still with little modification you can connect flutter variables with gradle files.

Here is the example https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/292/change-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion/ 

I hope it helps